# Safest way to store an authentication token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have my custom `AuthenticationProvider` which call a third party SSO to authenticate a user. If a user is valid I get an authentication token from the SSO service. I have to keep this token during the session for another services which will require this authentication token to verify the user has a valid session.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String id = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        JsonObject response = ssoClient.login(id, password);
        JsonObject session = response.getJsonObject("session");
        JsonObject user = session.getJsonObject("user");
        String email = user.getString("email");
        String username = user.getString("username");
        String fullname = user.getString("fullname");
        String auth_token = session.getString("auth_token");
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = null;
        return new CustomAuthenticationToken(username, auth_token, email, 
                fullname, grantedAuths);
}
```

I have extended from `AbstractAuthenticationToken` to create a custom `CustomAuthenticationToken` to store this token and another information. Should I sign this token with something like [itsdangeous](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/) (but in java) or encrypt it? Or should I store the authentication token in any other place? Thanks!

Comment: i`have seen people saving it as BLOB in mysql for later reusing. Might suit your need.

Comment: @BrankoIlic In this case I won't have any database for my web...

Comment: Could md5 the token and send it at the beginning of all requests. This is in no way the safest option.

Comment: @angeldev i am not quite sure i understand what you are saying. Just create new table within same mysql schema you use for your webapp called (for example) access_tokens and in there save token,expire_date, user, and whole authentication object as BLOB if you think you will need it later on, and any other information you find useful. This is the way it is normally done. I am not sure i answered your question, because it was unclear to me what was your concern.

Comment: @BrankoIlic what I mean is that I don't have any database for the web app. The database will be managed by another services, so I don't like to create a request to a service to get the token each time I need it.

Comment: Hmm right i get it. Well tokens are usually saved in "persistent" way, mongodb, mysql, there are in memory solutions which are not really suited for production. There is no silver bullet here. You may want to get few documents lightweight mongodb up and running and save tokens there. You will probably in time encounter the need to store additional information locally. I guess that is not too bad to have localdb as holder of temporary data.

Comment: @BrankoIlic my concern is that anyone can get this token, so probably I shoud encode it. Store it in a database, in session or in the SecurityContext probably doesn't matter if it is not encrypted? Thanks

Comment: If you think your token could get compromised feel free to encrypt it. Keep in mind that encrypt-decrypt adds overhead to your app. For this particular task you can use private signing key (or use something else, i personally sign information like this with private key because token validity is usually less than 30min) you can find more information here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Comment: @BrankoIlic yeah! probably this is useful! Thanks!